# data displaying from database in div with AJAX, jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to display data from database in one div when clicking on button

my controller :

```
        function search_course()
          {
        $this->load->view('pages/doctor-search');
        $this->load->model('DoctorSearch');
        $result=$this->DoctorSearch->search_course();
        echo json_encode($result);
```

}

My Model:

```
       function search_course()
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT userRef FROM users");
    echo $this->db->last_query();//die('jdshf');
    return $query->result();
 }
```

View:

```
      <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        alert("hello");
        $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url: "http://localhost/website/Controller/search_course",
            dataType:"json",
            data:req,
            success:
            function(data)
            {


               var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);
               var str='';
                str+='<ul>';
                $(function() {
                    $.each(responseData, function(i, item) {
                         str+='<li>'+item.userRef+'</li>';
                         alert("fdfg");
                    });
                })
                str+='</ul>';
                $('#test').html(str);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```
 <button> click me </button>
  <div id="test"> </div>
```

when i click on this button the data from database should be display in test id.
why the data is not calling.Anything mistake in my code

Comment: 1) have you checked network tab ajax request is invoking? 2) if yes, then what is returning?

Comment: Are you getting data to AJAX function? Run your url `http://localhost/website/Controller/search_course` separately and check. Then check `console.log(data)` inside your success function.

Comment: data getting.. but output not showing @SilentCoder

Comment: Can you show us sample data ?

Comment: remove that `data:req,` part and check

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert("hello");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "http://localhost/website/Controller/search_course",
            dataType:"json",
            data:'',
            success:
            function(data)
            {
               var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);
               var str='';
                str+='<ul>';
                $.each(responseData, function(key, value) {
                    str+='<li>'+value.userRef+'</li>';
                    alert("fdfg");
                });
                str+='</ul>';
                $('#test').html(str);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Remove req you are sending in data parameter. because you are sending no data

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution,

```
var url = "http://localhost/website/Controller/search_course";
 $.get(url, function (data, status) {
       var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);
       var str='<ul>';
       $.each(responseData, function(i, item) {
            str+='<li>'+item.userRef+'</li>';
       });
       str+='</ul>';
       $('#test').html(str);
 });
```

Comment: what is data here

Comment: data is your response, your response will attach to that parameter automatically.

Comment: not working @Silent

Comment: So better check whether controller gives the data out.? please try with @Nitin answer above.

Comment: detailed error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data